# What is a windows alternative to CODA 2s publishing feature?

Tags: windows, coda

I've moved over from Mac to Windows for a new job and I'm really struggling with FTP, I used to use CODA 2 for Mac which had a really great publishing feature. Are there any alternatives for Windows? If not what are your work flows like for working on a local copy but needing to publish on a live site?
Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 0):

> a new job

The ideal time to unlearn some bad practices.

> what are your work flows like for working on a local copy but needing to publish on a live site?

Like, not doing it at all. Publish to live through a Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery (CI/CD) environment through Development, Testing, Acceptance and Production ([DTAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production)).

If you don't want to do any of that and keep pushing changes from local to live without source control and testing environment, see for example [Keeping local windows folder in sync with remote ftp folder in real time](https://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time).